# Kalman filter for car's tracking path

Tags: algorithm, gps, tracking, linear-regression, kalman-filter

I am having a set of Points like `Point(x,y)`. After the car gone through so many ways in the same road it is almost messing the resulting map. I heard that **Kalman filter** can make a sigle path from the available paths.

Can any body say how to make it? I am not from computer science. So please explain me about that concept and those matrices. Then I will code them. Please anybody enlighten me about the concept.

Comment: What you actually want to do?

Comment: In my code a car is wandering in a map. But it don't know the exact path. So it may go in the same road twice or n times, but in different paths. Now If I collected those path points, I will have n set of points. Each set will contain the points of a path. Now from these available paths, I have to bring the original road. In other words I want the centre line of the road as a path.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know is the Kalman filter capable to combine several sources of the same information to get a more precise measurement of the observed variable. It could be possible to combine also with the same measruement device measured multiple times. 
Here is a good introduction:[INTRO](http://www.tristanfletcher.co.uk/LDS.pdf), [AnotherOne](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/media/pdf/kalman_intro.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still active, but if your intressted in learning more about the Kalman filter I can strongly recomend [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12307) short matlab script. Even if you dont have matlab installed it should be about the simplest example on Kalman your likely to find!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how exactly a Kalman filter would be applied here.

I would approach this problem either by image processing, so a thick path would be reduced to a thin line or by successive linear regression on the path segments.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to use the detected coordinates of a car, to determine where a road is, when there is no roadmap information available. Trying to create a road when there is no road, right?
The Kalman Filter is meant to smoothen values obtained from a sensor. When a sensor detects a car, the sensor may not give the car's actual position. It will contain some errors in x and y coordinates.
You have to feed these x,y values to the Kalman filter **while the data is being obtained from the sensor**. Or at least in the correct order that it was obtained from the sensor.
The Kalman filter will give you the estimated values (smoothened values) of x and y positions, which will tell you approximately the correct position of the car.

Assuming that the car is travelling in the middle of the road, these estimated (filtered) x,y values are what you can take as the midpoints of the road.
I saw your question only now. I know it's late, but I hope that helped?